# Remove active accordion when click on another accordion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with solving the JavaScript code for my sidebar. I saw a lot of reference and help are usually get it done by jQuery. I know jQuery is powerful but I prefer stay with regular JavaScript since I'm very new to it.

If you are reading this please don't anyhow mark as `duplicate` or `devote` because I'm doing the JavaScript research for sometime and I hope this post will become useful for myself and other people who want to use regular JavaScript.

Moving on, I actually learn to create a simple accordion from [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) which you can refer it at [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp).

In the meantime I have successfully create my custom sidebar. But the thing is I want my active accordion to be closed when clicked on other accordion.

Playground:

```js
const sideBar = document.getElementsByClassName('pisti-sidebar');

for (let i = 0; i < sideBar.length; i++) {
  sideBar[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    const sideBarTitle = this.nextElementSibling;

    sideBarTitle.style.display == 'none';

    if (sideBarTitle.style.display === 'block') {
      sideBarTitle.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      sideBarTitle.style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelectorAll('.pisti-sidebar')[i].classList.remove('onload-active');
      document.querySelectorAll('.pisti-sidebar-title')[i].classList.remove('onload-active');

    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #000000 !important;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* pisti-sidebar goes here */

.pisti-sidebar {
  background: none !important;
  border: none;
  border-left: 2px solid #888888;
  color: #888888;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 20px;
  text-align: left;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
  width: 100%;
}

.pisti-sidebar:first-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.pisti-sidebar-title {
  border-left: 2px solid #888888;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
}

.pisti-sidebar:hover {
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #f7cc1b;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
}

.pisti-sidebar-active,
.pisti-sidebar:active,
.pisti-sidebar:focus {
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #f7cc1b !important;
  outline: none;
}

.pisti-sidebar:focus+.pisti-sidebar-title {
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
}

.pisti-sidebar-content {
  color: #888888 !important;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0px 30px 10px 30px;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
}

.pisti-sidebar-content:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
}

.pisti-sidebar-content:first-child {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.pisti-sidebar-content:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}


/* pisti-sidebar active */

.onload-active {
  color: #f7cc1b;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
}

.onload-unactive {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-color: #888888;
}

.pisti-sidebar:focus+.pisti-sidebar-title {
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
}

.pisti-sidebar-title-active {
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.pisti-sidebar-title-active,
.pisti-sidebar-content-active {
  color: #f7cc1b !important;
}

.pisti-sidebar-content-active::before {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  content: '';
  height: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <button class="pisti-sidebar onload-active" data-pisti-sidebar="pisti-sidebar-1">Appareal</button>
      <!-- pisti-sidebar-active -->
      <div class="pisti-sidebar-title onload-active">
        <!-- pisti-sidebar-title-active -->
        <a href="#" class="pisti-sidebar-content">Custom shirt</a>
        <a href="#" class="pisti-sidebar-content">Event shirt</a>
        <a href="#" class="pisti-sidebar-content">Corporate shirt</a>
        <!-- pisti-sidebar-content-active -->
      </div>

      <button class="pisti-sidebar" data-pisti-sidebar="pisti-sidebar-2">Digital Printing</button>
      <!-- pisti-sidebar-active -->
      <div class="pisti-sidebar-title">
        <!-- pisti-sidebar-title-active -->
        <a href="#" class="pisti-sidebar-content">Poster</a>
        <a href="#" class="pisti-sidebar-content">Banner</a>
        <a href="#" class="pisti-sidebar-content">Bunting</a>
        <!-- pisti-sidebar-content-active -->
      </div>

      <button class="pisti-sidebar" data-pisti-sidebar="pisti-sidebar-3">Offset Printing</button>
      <!-- pisti-sidebar-active -->
      <div class="pisti-sidebar-title">
        <!-- pisti-sidebar-title-active -->
        <a href="#" class="pisti-sidebar-content">Name card</a>
        <a href="#" class="pisti-sidebar-content">Flyer</a>
        <a href="#" class="pisti-sidebar-content">Booklet</a>
        <!-- pisti-sidebar-content-active -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For further explain I actually added:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.pisti-sidebar')[0].classList.remove('onload-active');
document.querySelectorAll('.pisti-sidebar-title')[0].classList.remove('onload-active');
```

to remove the class on first accordion so it will close it. But I have no idea how can I close the second accordion when I clicked on third or first accordion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the CSS & JS to exclude the list being toggled in the `for` loop. Instead just toggle the `.active` class on the button and use the adjacent selector `.pisti-sidebar.active + .pisti-sidebar-title` to show its list.

```js
const sideBars = document.getElementsByClassName('pisti-sidebar');

for (let sideBar of sideBars) {
  sideBar.onclick = e => {
    var thisEl = e.target;
    if (thisEl.classList.contains('active')) {
      thisEl.classList.remove('active');
    } else {
      thisEl.classList.add('active');
      for (activeSideBar of sideBars) {
        if (activeSideBar != thisEl) {
          activeSideBar.classList.remove('active');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #000000 !important;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
}

.pisti-sidebar {
  background: none !important;
  border: none;
  border-left: 2px solid #888888;
  color: #888888;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 20px;
  text-align: left;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
  width: 100%;
}

.pisti-sidebar:first-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.pisti-sidebar-title {
  border-left: 2px solid #888888;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
}

.pisti-sidebar:active,
.pisti-sidebar:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.pisti-sidebar.active+.pisti-sidebar-title {
  display: block;
}

.pisti-sidebar-content {
  color: #888888 !important;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0px 30px 10px 30px;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
}

.pisti-sidebar-content:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
}

.pisti-sidebar-content:first-child {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.pisti-sidebar-content:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.active {
  color: #f7cc1b;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
}

.onload-unactive {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-color: #888888;
}

.pisti-sidebar:focus+.pisti-sidebar-title {
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
}

.pisti-sidebar-title-active {
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.pisti-sidebar-title-active,
.pisti-sidebar-content-active {
  color: #f7cc1b !important;
}

.pisti-sidebar-content-active::before {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  content: '';
  height: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <button class="pisti-sidebar active" data-pisti-sidebar="pisti-sidebar-1">Appareal</button>
      <!-- pisti-sidebar-active -->
      <div class="pisti-sidebar-title">
        <!-- pisti-sidebar-title-active -->
        <a href="#" class="pisti-sidebar-content">Custom shirt</a>
        <a href="#" class="pisti-sidebar-content">Event shirt</a>
        <a href="#" class="pisti-sidebar-content">Corporate shirt</a>
        <!-- pisti-sidebar-content-active -->
      </div>

      <button class="pisti-sidebar" data-pisti-sidebar="pisti-sidebar-2">Digital Printing</button>
      <!-- pisti-sidebar-active -->
      <div class="pisti-sidebar-title">
        <!-- pisti-sidebar-title-active -->
        <a href="#" class="pisti-sidebar-content">Poster</a>
        <a href="#" class="pisti-sidebar-content">Banner</a>
        <a href="#" class="pisti-sidebar-content">Bunting</a>
        <!-- pisti-sidebar-content-active -->
      </div>

      <button class="pisti-sidebar" data-pisti-sidebar="pisti-sidebar-3">Offset Printing</button>
      <!-- pisti-sidebar-active -->
      <div class="pisti-sidebar-title">
        <!-- pisti-sidebar-title-active -->
        <a href="#" class="pisti-sidebar-content">Name card</a>
        <a href="#" class="pisti-sidebar-content">Flyer</a>
        <a href="#" class="pisti-sidebar-content">Booklet</a>
        <!-- pisti-sidebar-content-active -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```